# Webpack build or TypeScript is creating JS files right in my SRC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, webpack

I don't undrestand what's doing this.  This doesn't seem normal right?  I am getting a `.js` file generated for every `.tsx` or `.ts` file after I build but *this shouldn't be in my source*.  I should only see .js files in my build obviously.

**My Scripts**

```
"start": "PORT=3000 nodemon --trace-warnings --experimental-json-modules --no-warnings dist/server/server.js",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production yarn lint && yarn copyData && yarn compile-server && yarn start & webpack -p --env=prod --watch",
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development yarn lint && yarn copyData && yarn compile-server && yarn start & webpack-dev-server -d --watch",
```

[image]
./**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () =>
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: true,
    });

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () =>
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
            { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css', to: 'lib/css' },
            { from: 'ext/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/fonts', to: 'lib/css/fonts' },
            { from: 'feed.xml', to: './' },
        ],
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: false,
        publicPath: '/',
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/',
        },
        stats: 'errors-only',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            },
        },
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../../',
                            outputPath: 'lib/css',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|otf|svg)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: '/lib/css/fonts', // <--resolve the path in css files
                            outputPath: 'lib/css/fonts', // <-- path to place font files
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: isProduction
        ? [
                new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ]
        : [
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ],
};
```

./**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",                     /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2020",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],                      /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,                     /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,                   /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "rootDir": "./",                     /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    "removeComments": true,              /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],                      /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "/node_modules",
        "/src/server",
        "/src/client/js/ink-config.js",
        "**/test",
        "dist"
  ]
}
```

./src/server/**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/server", /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "."                 /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "include": ["./*.ts"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662777/typescript-automatically-creating-js-files-after-running-npm-start

Comment: not really I don't see why I'd need an `outDir` if webpack is building almost everything for me and bundles to its own specified output directory.  I'm not asking tsconfig to output all the ts files for my build.  webpack is bundling and using typescript to process my bundle.  I need the bundle webpack creates, not a js file per everything webpack just bundled too right??  maybe I'm just really confused here.  I only have a child tsconfig outputting something for my server, but the rest is bundled by webpack for the client side

Comment: What happens if you add `"outDir": "dist"` under `"compilerOptions"`?

Comment: Side-by-side emit is the default. There are a lot of good reason for this including it makes it much easier for people to get started. If you only want webpack to compile, use the noEmit option

Comment: If I add `"outDir": "dist"` then it just outputs all those .js files to dist instead of src but I don't want that as my webpack bundle already included all those js files during the build

Comment: thanks let me try `noEmit`.  Seems stupid to manage your build in both webpack AND TS TBH.  That's confusing as hell.  The entire point is to maintain your build for client-side with webpack anyway.

Comment: @PositiveGuy the point for you maybe to manage your client build with webpack, but there are other tools. TypeScript is a good citizen of the JavaScript ecosystem and attempts to be agnostic, working with various build tools. Example if you use a system JS tool chain, this is a non-issue you don't have to set no emit

Comment: yea I just think it's really confusing when you can do some of both in TS and webpack.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Of course you don't have to do it this way as you can just have webpack process JS files that are output by TSC. I would not recommend that. Ideally, the webpack loader would not create any output files by default. There are webpack typescript loaders that have this Behavior

Comment: the problem I have now though is because I put `"noEmit": true`, webpack errors during its build saying it can't bundle index.tsx anymore.  It's using `ts-loader` and that fails I think or something.  Oh so is ts-loader allowing webpack to bundle the output TS via tsconfig?

Comment: That's very weird. It should absolutely be ignoring that flag because it doesn't make sense in a webpack context. Try awesome typescript loader. I've never had these issues using that

Comment: yea ts-loader looks for output from tsconfig.  ERROR in ./src/client/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /Users/coffeegrinds/code/other/projects/we-do-tdd/src/client/index.tsx.  So we have a chicken totally conflicting issue now

Comment: awesome typescript loader: This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only

Comment: Another option you have, is just to override that one option in the loader configuration for ts-loader. You can specify in line configuration

Comment: Oh crap, they merge it into TS loader didn't they. I had forgotten

Comment: yea hmm I'm stuck now

Comment: I still don't understand why it's outputting files to disk though it shouldn't be doing that I've never seen that happen. Are you running TSC from the command line as well?

Comment: yea I run `yarn dev`, my script is in the post

Comment: so for now I'm telling TS to output to an intermediate "build" directory while webpack bundles everytihing to "dist": `"outDir": "./build"`.  That way I can keep it out of my dist and src :).

Comment: So seems to work, telling TS to output to `build`.  webpack uses `ts-loader` to then process those `build` folder JS files outputted by tsconfig, and then webpack is set to output the bundle into `dist`.  Works great now this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My resolution was to:**

1. Since I was using `ts-loader` in webpack, it expects tsconfig to emit `.js` files that webpack can then process via the loader
2. Due to #1, I couldn't just set the emit to false in tsconfig because webpack relies on processing the outputted js files so that it can create a bundle off them ultimately
3. Since I don't want those intermediate js files that are generated by tsconfig cluttering my `src` folder, I set my tsconfig output directory to be `build`
4. webpack's output directory is `dist` so I will end up with only the production build

By doing this, the intermediate TS js files are outputted to `build`, picked up by webpack, processed into a bundle, and bundle is outputted to `dist`.

./**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "outDir": "./build",
}
```

./**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
output: {
  filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
{
  test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
  use: 'ts-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
},
```

This kept everything clean.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it appears Visual Studio was using it's built in TypeScript compiler to generate the js files.

Since I only want webpack to create js files in my dist folder I was able to disable visual studio's built in behavior by adding this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
 </PropertyGroup>
```