# WebStorm create .js file when create .tsx automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm IDE and make CRA TypeScript project.

My coworker get something strange situation. When she create `.tsx` file, `.js` file create together.
And It's icon has `x` mark unlike other `JS`files.

In contrast, when I create `.tsx` file, just `.tsx`made.
What is this file and why create differently? I think it's because of WebStorm setting but couldn't find difference.

We check `Setting > Code style > TypeScript > Imports tab`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack build or TypeScript is creating JS files right in my SRC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422959/webpack-build-or-typescript-is-creating-js-files-right-in-my-src)

Comment: @s0xzwasd Thanks but it looks not problem of webpack build. It happens when **create** file

Answer (score 3):

You must have **Recompile on changes** enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** - when this option is on, the built-in compiler service emits the `.js` files for your Typescript sources. As you are using CRA that takes care of your `.tsx` and `.ts` files, piping them through a chain of webpack loaders, you don't need having this option enabled, please consider turning it off

Comment: It creates when **create new file** on root folder. I guess it's not problem about Typescript recompile option.

Comment: did you check if the option is enabled per my suggestion?